# declare a method of TForm1 (vcl)

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I want to test the sample code at the following Embarcadero link:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/ShowException_(C%2B%2B)

The description says

> AppException should be declared a method of TForm1.

I don't know how to do that - **declare a method of TForm1**.

How is that done?

---

UPDATE: The solution was to put the `AppException` method in the `Unit1.h` file under the `private` section:

```cpp
private:    // User declarations
void __fastcall TForm1::AppException(TObject *Sender, Exception *E)
{
  Application->ShowException(E);
  Application->Terminate();
}
```

Comment: Just create a new `VCL application`. Once you do that, an instance of `TForm1` will already be generated for you (by default). Now, add the `AppException` method to both cpp and header files. Declaring a method of `TForm1` means making it a member of `TForm1`.

Comment: Thank you dsp_user, this pointed me in the right direction.  I just needed to put the code under the private: section of the h file.  I've modified my post to show it above.  Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, you are allowed to post your own answer to your own question, you shouldn't edit the question to provide the answer. In any case, only the **declaration** of `AppException()` belongs in `Unit1.h`, the **definition** (body) belongs in `Unit1.cpp` instead.  An easier way to handle this is to not manually assign the `Application->OnException` event at all, but instead to drop a [`TApplicationEvents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents) component onto the Form at design-time and then use the Object Inspector to generate an `OnException` event handler.